# Updating one observableArray while looping another observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

Given one observableArray, populated by a service call, which is used to render a Checkbox list in a view:

```
orgChart = ko.observableArray();
```

- Id
- Dept

And another observableArray, populated by another service, which returns a list of Id's for those Departments which have been selected (in the DB) from the above array.

```
selectedDepartment = ko.observableArray();
```

- Id

How do I get knockout to bind to the second array when looping over the first?

I tried this, which renders the Checkbox list, but fails to update the selectedDepartment array.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: orgChart">
 <div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedDepartment, value: Id }"/><span data-bind="text: Dept"/></div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing that I need to use a mapping or computed value, but I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to have just one observableArray, not two.

Combine the data received from your 2 service calls into a list of objects.

For example,

```
var orgChart = getDataFromFirstServiceCall();
var selectedDepartments = getDataFromSecondServiceCall();

var vm = {
    departments = ko.observableArray(),
}

function Department( id , name ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.selected = selectedDepartments.indexOf(id) !== -1;
}

for( var i = 0; i < orgChart.length; i++ ) {
    var dept = orgChart[i];
    vm.departments.push( new Department( dept.id , dept.name );
}

ko.applyBindings( vm );
```

Now in your HTML you can do this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: departments">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected }" />
        <span data-bind="text: name"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

To send the data back to the server, simply loop through the departments array and grab the ones with the `selected` flag set to `true`

```
var departments = vm.departments(),
    selected = [];
for( var i = 0; i < departments.length; i++ ) {
    var dept = departments[i];
    if( dept.selected ) selected.push(dept);
}
```

Voila!

Or if you want to save bandwidth and/or delete/insert statements to the DB, you can make `selected` an observable, subscribe to it's changes and then save it to the server individually.

```
function Department( id , name ) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.selected = ko.observable( selectedDepartments.indexOf(id) !== -1 );
    self.selected.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        // save newValue to the database
        // perform an ajax POST, sending self.id and newValue
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my only concern with this strategy is that I need the selectedDepartments variable to be observable, so that it can be saved back to the DB.

Comment: I thought you might ask that. Check out my edit. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again, I'm going to give it a try!  I'll give it a check if it works.